# Loop through different elements?

Tags: c#, xml, loops

I have some XML as such:

```
<Step>
<Check>...</Check>
<Check>...</Check>
<Action>...</Action>
</Step>
```

I want to loop through the sub nodes of `<Step>`.  I know this line:

```
foreach (XElement substep in document.Descendants("Check"))
```

Loops through the  elements only, how can I loop through the `<Check>` elements and the `<Action>` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the elements descendant from Step:

```
foreach (var element in document.Element("Step").Elements())
{

}
```

Comment: I'm confused by this. `Elements("Step")` is going to return an `IEnumerable<XElement>`, which doesn't have an `Elements()` method...

Comment: Fixed! The Element method returns the first Element matched by Name

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the `XName` filter. This will enumerate through all of the child elements.

```
foreach (XElement substep in document.Root.Elements())
```

If you want to only visit `Check` and `Action` elements, add in

```
.Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Check" || x.Name.LocalName == "Action")
```